# Android AlarmManager scheduling through time zone or daylight shifts

Tags: android, timezone, alarmmanager, android-broadcast, dst

I have a logic that schedules reminders using AlarmManager. I need to implement the following:

**Logic 1**: when the user changes time zone, eg he travels from UK (UTC+0) to central Europe (UTC+1), alarms should follow the time zone.
Example, a reminder scheduled at 3PM UTC+0 should fire at 4PM UTC+1

**Logic 2**: when a time shift occurs, eg time shifts to daylight saving time in spring (from UTC+1 to UTC+2), alarms should keep the original time
Example, a reminder scheduled at 3PM UTC+1 should fire at 3PM UTC+2

How can I achieve this? As of now I have no particular logic in place and all the alarms follow *Logic 1*. I have found no way to identify when a time shift happens.

Scheduling logic is very simple:

```
LocalDateTime reminderTime = LocalDateTime.of(...)
ZoneOffset currentOffsetForMyZone = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
reminderTime.toInstant(currentOffsetForMyZone).toEpochMilli();
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderTime, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Why not just use UTC and not worry about time zones?

Comment: How can I implement the two logics above using just UTC?

Comment: UTC time does not change, it has no timezone and no daylight savings. you can use the `Calendar` to get the UTC timestamp of a specific date

Comment: It doesn't work. In your scenario all alarms are rescheduled using logic 1 of my question. When time switches to DST all the alarms are rescheduled as well, instead I need to keep the actual time (logic 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the fix was to apply the correct offset for the date and time where the alarm is to go of, as pointed out by Ole. My silly mistake was to apply always the *current* timezone.

```
LocalDateTime alarmTime = LocalDateTime.of(...)
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(alarmTime , zone);
long startAtMillis = zoneDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
//Fire alarm
notificationAlarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startAtMillis, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

For each alarm store the time of day and the time zone in which it was set. This suffices for firing the alarm at the right time no matter if the user is currently in a different time zone. And Java will take summer time (DST) into account.

Your example times and UTC offsets correspond to standard time in those time zones, so let’s start with an example date in standard time even though it was a couple of days ago now:

```
    LocalTime alarmTime = LocalTime.of(15, 0);
    ZoneId alarmTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    
    // Travel to Paris and see the alarm go off at 4, assuming standard time
    ZoneId currentTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
    Instant actualAlarmTime = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 18)
            .atTime(alarmTime)
            .atZone(alarmTimeZone)
            .toInstant();
    ZonedDateTime timeOnLocation = actualAlarmTime.atZone(currentTimeZone);
    System.out.format("Scheduled at %s or %d millis, goes off at %s local time%n",
            actualAlarmTime, actualAlarmTime.toEpochMilli(), timeOnLocation);
```

The code prints:

> Scheduled at 2021-03-18T15:00:00Z or 1616079600000 millis, goes off at
> 2021-03-18T16:00+01:00[Europe/Paris] local time

Let’s also try a date in the summer time part of the year. I have changed `Paris` to `London` and `MARCH` to `APRIL`:

```
    // Stay back home in the UK
    ZoneId currentTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    Instant actualAlarmTime = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.APRIL, 18)
            .atTime(alarmTime)
            .atZone(alarmTimeZone)
            .toInstant();
```

> Scheduled at 2021-04-18T14:00:00Z or 1618754400000 millis, goes off at
> 2021-04-18T15:00+01:00[Europe/London] local time

The basic trick is: don’t use the *current*  offset for the time zone where you set the alarm. Let Java automatically apply the offset for the date and time where the alarm is to go off.

Comment: Timezone changes work, thanks. I'm still having troubles to figure out how to manage DST timeshifts (logic 2). AlarmManager works at absolute time only and I receive no events when timeshift occurs. Do I have to set my own alarm?

Comment: Ok I think I understood what you said. My scheduling logic was wrong and the solution in fact was really easy.