# Why AlarmClockInfo is earlier than the act?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, utc

I was trying to get the next alarm clock, by the following which returns the next clock timestamp of utc wall time.

```
val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
val next = alarmManager.nextAlarmClock.triggerTime
```

If the next clock is at 19:00 of tomorrow, the `next` will result of 18:00 of tomorrow, what is the difference of `utc wall time` and `utc time`, I have googled for nothing.

Comment: AIK, this returns `UTC wall clock time` (or local time), that means the time depends on the time zone of the clock which is controlled by local governmental authorities. UTC (or exact time) however has a consistent global definition. [Read more here](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/ambiguity.html) . So, the `long` value of `triggerTime` should be parsed with the zone offset here.

Comment: @NamNH My time zone is +8 UTC, it is not right yet.

Comment: Twlkyao, re-verify the zone setting on your device. Also, try to change to other timezone and see the relation.

Comment: @NamNH how to parse wall clock time with zone offset

Comment: Maybe this post could help you.
The key is to use the default timezone, so you do not have wall clock time issues.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859079/android-alarmmanager-scheduling-through-time-zone-or-daylight-shifts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I change a phone, there may be some fault on the first phone, because the result is not consistent when the alarm clock changes.